# Collapsing duplicated samples in Generalized Least Squares

Tags: covariance, least-squares

I am trying to solve the Generalized Least Squares problem:

$\hat{\beta} =  (X^T\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T\Omega^{-1}y$

I have duplicated rows in $X$. I would like to remove the duplicated rows and apply an appropriate weight to the corresponding rows/columns in $\Omega$.

In the Weighted Least Squares case, I would just apply the weights directly to the diagonal terms in the covariance matrix (e.g. if the first row is duplicated 3 times I could replace the rows with one and a sample weight of 3).

In the generalized case, how should I weight the off-diagonal terms in the covariance matrix?

Comment: Even in the WLS case it's not as simple as you represent, because you have to do something with $y,$ too.